# Importing text files into master excel document (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code that allows the user to select a folder, and then it loops through all the files in the folder, copying a specific column of data into my master document 'PQ Analysis spreadsheet'.

I would like to improve this code, to make it more generic.

Is there any way I can alter it so I don't have to specify 'PQ Analysis spreadsheet' as the master document? i.e. So it can be called whatever the user wishes.

Additionally, I currently open each file into a new workbook, and copy from there. I'm sure there must be a way to input directly from the txt file into an array, and print from there?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is the first VBA code I have written, so am very new to this language! Thanks.

```
Sub tabdelim()
Dim strFileToOpen
Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook

'Dialogue box to select file to open
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Text Files *.txt* (*.txt*),")

If strFileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "No file selected!"
    Exit Sub

Else
    'Open selected file in new workbook
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    strFileToOpen, _
    Origin:=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
    Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


End If


Set InputFile = ActiveWorkbook

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile:
ActiveSheet.Range("I3:I660").Copy


'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
Windows("PQ Analysis spreadsheet.xls").Activate
Set OutputFile = ActiveWorkbook
Range("C43").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'Close InputFile
InputFile.Close


End Sub
```

[image: example of txt document input]

Comment: `Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = InputBox("Select a workbook")`

Comment: Using Power Query would be simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, a launcher to select files, and commence import on each file:

```
Sub SelectFilesForImport()
    Dim fd  As FileDialog
    Dim i   As Long

    'set and determine file picker behaviors
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    'Launch file picker, exit if no files selected. 
    'Hold Ctrl to select multiple files. Ctrl+A to select all files
    If Not fd.Show = -1 Then Exit Sub

    'Start import selected files, file by file.
    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        Call ImportFile(fd.SelectedItems(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Second sub, import line by line (w/o opening the file in Excel)

```
Private Sub ImportFile(ByVal FilePathAndName As String)
    Dim DataInTransit   As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim N               As Integer

    N = FreeFile
    Open FilePathAndName For Input As #N
        Do While Not EOF(N)
            Line Input #N, DataInTransit

            ' ##################################################
            ' Up to this point, "DataInTransit" is a single line text.
            ' Now it depends on how you want to massage and put it into the worksheet.
            ' You can also skip lines which do not fit into context _
              by adding conditional IF statements.
            ' Modify below to suit your needs:
                Arr = Split(DataInTransit, ";")
                ActiveCell.Resize(1, UBound(Arr) + 1) = Split(DataInTransit, " ")
                ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate
            ' ##################################################

        Loop
    Close #N
End Sub
```

For where to place the import, I think it simpler to place directly into `ActiveCell` as shown is second sub above, then offset to next row for new lines. But it could be slow if you have many calculations (could be solve by turn of automatic calculation). Otherwise, as you suggested, use array to collect the lines and then put them in all at once into the worksheet. Either way, the user only have to select the top-left corner of the range where to begin the import (It would be nice to prompt a message to ask them to select the cell where to begin placing the import, otherwise they could mess up their whole worksheet, p/s also allow them to cancel the macro in the prompt for just in case). This can be done by simply adding the lines below into the first sub.

```
    Dim k
    k = Application.InputBox("Please select where to place the import.")
    On Error GoTo Term 'If k is not a range, go to Term
    Range(k).Activate
    Exit Sub

    Term:
    End
```